# ggplot2: Changing the order of stacks on a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart, facet-wrap

I'm trying to make a stacked bar graph with a facet_wrap, but I want the order of my stacked variables ("developed") to be flipped.  I've reordered the factors, and tried "order=descend()," as well as "scale_fill_manual" and nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
developed=rep(c("developed","available"),6)
agriculture=rep(c(rep("loi",2), rep("dryland",2), rep("agroforestry",2)),2)  
acres=c(7435,24254,10609,120500,10651,75606,6037,9910,4390,895,9747,46893)
islands=c(rep("All islands",6), rep("Oahu",6))
all_is2=data.frame(developed, agriculture, acres, islands)
head(all_is2)
  developed  agriculture  acres      island
1 developed          loi   7435 All islands
2 available          loi  24254 All islands
3 developed      dryland  10609 All islands
4 available      dryland 120500 All islands
5 developed agroforestry  10651 All islands
6 available agroforestry  75606 All islands
```

changing factor levels of "agriculture" and "developed"

```
all_is2$agriculture=factor(all_is2$agriculture,levels=c("loi","dryland","agroforestry"))
all_is2$developed=factor(all_is2$developed,levels=c("developed","available"))
levels(all_is2$developed)
[1] "developed" "available"
```

Then, plotting:

```
ggplot(all_is2,aes(x=agriculture,y=acres,fill=developed))+
     geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
     facet_wrap(~islands)+ scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.2, name="")+ xlab("")+ylab("Acres")+theme_bw()+ scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)
```

[image: The Graph]

I want the "developed" parts of the bars in gray on top of the "available" parts of the bars, which are black.  And the legend should match the order of the bars as well.

Also, is it possible to move the facet_wrap "All islands" and "Oahu" at the top to the bottom of the graph under "loi" "dryland" and "agroforestry."  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You need to reverse the order of your factors. (`levels=c("available","developed")`). And facets are always on top or besides the plot, if you want labels below an approach with grid.arrange might be the way to go.

Comment: I've tried that, leaving the factors at levels=c("available","developed"), but what I get is the available stacked on top in gray and developed stacks on the bottom in black. (http://imgur.com/ne3iNhk)

Comment: Almost seems like a bug.

Comment: On the facets, with thanks to @Jota: you can use `facet_wrap(~islands , switch = "x")`

Comment: I think [this issue on ggplot github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1472) is related.

Comment: Thank you everyone i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 11):

This might be a solution.

What I did was ordering the dataset, so that the value I wanted to appear closest to the x-axis appeared first in the dataset. (I've used your ordering of factors here). This fixt the positioning of the bars.

Then, we had to change the colors and order of the legend. I could not wrap my head around scale_fill_grey, so I changed it to scale_fill_manual instead, setting both values and breaks.

```
ggplot(all_is2[rev(order(all_is2$developed)),] ,aes(x=agriculture,y=acres,fill=developed))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~islands)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(developed="grey80",available="grey20"),name="",
                    breaks=c("developed","available"))+
 xlab("")+ylab("Acres")
```

[image]

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, and I think this also happened with previous versions in ggplot, but it appears that with stat_identity the first observation is plotted closest to the x-axis, the second on top of that etc.

Demonstration:

```
set.seed(123)
testdat <- data.frame(x=1,y=sample(5))


p1 <- ggplot(testdat, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=factor(y))) +geom_bar(stat="identity")+labs(title="order in dataset")
p2 <- ggplot(testdat[order(testdat$y),],aes(x=x,y=y,fill=factor(y))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + labs(title="ordered by y")
p3 <- ggplot(testdat[rev(order(testdat$y)),],aes(x=x,y=y,fill=factor(y))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + labs(title="reverse ordered by y")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, you beat me! Check out `facet_wrap(~islands , switch = "x")` for moving the facet labels below.  It's a new feature of `ggplot2_2.0.0`

Comment: The fact you have to control the plot by ordering the dataset seems odd. But I thought it used `dplyr` internally, so it might be the same as mine.

Comment: I used ggplot2.0; the `order`-aesthetic has been officially deprecated and someone suggesting ordering data to obtain the same effect.

Comment: You're actually making it a bit more complicated than it needs to be; you just need to order the data and that's it. The order of the legend is controlled by the order of the factor levels; the order of the plot by the order of the data: http://ilari.scheinin.fi/ggplot-2-0-and-the-missing-order-aesthetic/

Comment: Thank you everyone!  I appreciate your help! @Heroka it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If it worked to your satisfaction, could you accept it? Keeps others from spending time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, here is a solution with `dplyr`, and it uses `scale_fill_manual` to be explicit about the colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

developed=rep(c("developed","available"),6)
agriculture=rep(c(rep("loi",2), rep("dryland",2), rep("agroforestry",2)),2)  
acres=c(7435,24254,10609,120500,10651,75606,6037,9910,4390,895,9747,46893)
islands=c(rep("All islands",6), rep("Oahu",6))
all_is2=data.frame(developed, agriculture, acres, islands)

all_is2$agriculture=factor(all_is2$agriculture,levels=c("loi","dryland","agroforestry"))
#all_is2$developed=factor(all_is2$developed,levels=c("available","developed"))

all_is3 <- all_is2 %>% group_by(islands,agriculture,developed) %>% 
                       summarize(acres=sum(acres)) 

ggplot(all_is3,aes(x=agriculture,y=acres,fill=developed))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~islands)+ 
  xlab("")+ylab("Acres")+theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(name="",values=c("available"="black","developed"="light gray"))
```

[image]

Comment: Your welcome, and I thought it was a good question from the start. I learned something from it. Glad to see you got all those upvotes too (one is mine), you are well established now.

Comment: Yeah this was my first post because it was so aggravating, and I really couldn't find a solution online for days.  But it was good to go through posting, I learned a lot too!

Comment: It must be morning there. I am ending my day :)