# How to change the order of the stacked bar charts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

My current data looks something like this
df:

```
Year     Labels   Cost    Order
2006     A        1000       1
2007     B        2000       2
2008     B        2000       2
2009     C        3000       4
2010     NA        0         NA
etc.
```

As of now, my stacked chart is in the form of 1,2,4,NA
I want to create a stacked chart of bar chart such that the bars are arranged in the following order (4,2,1,NA).

Ive tried:

```
ggplot(df[order(df$order,decreasing=T),],
             aes(x=x,y=y,fill=labels))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But my order is the same.
Anyone have any advice using dplyr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2: Changing the order of stacks on a bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716245/ggplot2-changing-the-order-of-stacks-on-a-bar-graph)

Comment: you need to set the `levels` of x to the order you're looking for. Changing the order of rows don't affect the plotting order.

Comment: How do I set the levels of x? could you guide me on how to tweak my codes? thanks!

Comment: Previous comment for @waterling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that might help you to change the levels of Order column:

```
df$Order <- factor(df$Order, levels = order(df$Order,decreasing=T))
```