# Make ggplot2 heatmap with different colors for values over/under thresholds

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

I want to make a table with cells highlighted according to their value, Perc_Diff in this case.  I want values between -100 and +100 to follow a scale_fill_gradient2 pattern (see code below), but values <= -100 to be blue, and values of >= 100 to be yellow.  Here is the data (some of it has been changed to illustrate my question).

```
plot30 <- structure(list(Station = structure(c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("WTES2", 
"WRIS2", "WEBS2", "VGAS2", "UNIS2", "TIMS2", "STMS2", "SHSS2", 
"SFWS2", "SFSS2", "RDFS2", "RBMS2", "PSTS2", "PRFS2", "ORRS2", 
"OCMS2", "OAKS2", "NISS2", "MHTS2", "MCTS2", "MCMS2", "MATS2", 
"LMNS2", "LLAS2", "JWLS2", "HMLS2", "HIHS2", "GTBS2", "GOTS2", 
"FLNS2", "FLKS2", "EGBS2", "EDTS2", "CTWS2", "CTNS2", "CPTS2", 
"CLRS2", "BWLS2", "BTNS2", "BTCS2", "BSNS2", "BKMS2", "BFMS2", 
"AURS2", "ATRS2"), class = "factor"), Comp_Data = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Total_QPE", 
"Stn_PP", "Diff_in", "Perc_Diff", "Frz_Days", "Miss_Days"), class = "factor"), 
    stuff = c(3.831, 3.07, -0.761, -24.79, 0, 0, 3.075, 1.81, 
    -1.265, -69.89, 0, 5, 2.941, 2.2, -0.741, -33.68, 0, 0, 2.907, 
    2.33, -0.577, -24.76, 0, 0, 2.319, 0.36, -1.959, -100, 0, 
    19, 2.241, 1.24, -1.001, -80.73, 0, 0, 1.926, 1.23, -0.696, 
    -56.59, 0, 0, 1.91, 1.07, -0.84, -78.5, 0, 0, 1.877, 1.47, 
    -0.407, -27.69, 0, 0, 1.867, 1.35, -0.517, -38.3, 0, 0, 1.773, 
    1.22, -0.553, -45.33, 0, 0, 1.773, 1.43, -0.343, -23.99, 
    0, 0, 1.717, 1.35, -0.367, -27.19, 0, 0, 1.659, 0.71, -0.949, 
    -100, 0, 0, 1.481, 0.5, -0.981, -100, 0, 0, 1.401, 0.23, 
    -1.171, -100, 0, 2, 1.377, 0.08, -1.297, -100, 0, 0, 1.296, 
    0.97, -0.326, -33.61, 0, 0, 1.263, 0.8, -0.463, -57.88, 0, 
    0, 1.255, 1.06, -0.195, -18.4, 0, 0, 1.212, 0.63, -0.582, 
    -92.38, 0, 0, 1.203, 0.71, -0.493, -69.44, 0, 0, 1.189, 0.01, 
    -1.179, -100, 0, 0, 1.18, 0.53, -0.65, -100, 0, 0, 1.144, 
    0.42, -0.724, -100, 0, 0, 1.105, 0.65, -0.455, -70, 0, 0, 
    1.062, 0.62, -0.442, -71.29, 0, 0, 1.043, 0.45, -0.593, -100, 
    0, 0, 1.032, 0.68, -0.352, -51.76, 0, 13, 0.99, 0.66, -0.33, 
    -50, 0, 0, 0.985, 0.67, -0.315, -47.01, 0, 0, 0.972, 0.7, 
    -0.272, -38.86, 0, 0, 0.946, 0.5, -0.446, -89.2, 0, 0, 0.916, 
    0.63, -0.286, -45.4, 0, 0, 0.87, 0.55, -0.32, -58.18, 0, 
    5, 0.854, 0.6, -0.254, -42.33, 0, 0, 0.825, 0.56, -0.265, 
    -47.32, 0, 0, 0.816, 0.74, -0.076, -10.27, 0, 0, 0.808, 0.24, 
    -0.568, -100, 0, 6, 0.765, 0.577, -0.188, -32.58, 0, 4, 0.723, 
    0.79, 0.067, 8.48, 0, 0, 0.713, 0.66, -0.053, -8.03, 0, 0, 
    0.647, 0.79, 0.143, 18.1, 0, 0, 0.452, 0.4, -0.052, -13, 
    0, 0, 0.328, 0.5, 0.172, 34.4, 0, 0), Perc_Diff = c(0, 0, 
    0, -24.79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -69.89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -33.68, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -24.76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     
    -80.73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -56.59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -78.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -27.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -38.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -45.33, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -23.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -27.19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -33.61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -57.88, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -18.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -92.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -69.44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -71.29, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -51.76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    -50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -38.86, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -89.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -45.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -58.18, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -42.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -10.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -32.58, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 8.48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34.4, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-270L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my working code to make the plot, but without the values above or below 100 specially colored:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot30, aes(Comp_Data, Station)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Perc_Diff),color='black') + geom_text(aes(label = stuff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = 'white', high = "red",limits=c(min(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T), max(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T))) +
  ggtitle(paste('30 Day Precipitation Comparison (Inches) for',date_30,'to',date_1,'\nCell Values Represent Differences (SD Mesonet minus QPE; Inches)')) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(3, "cm")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0))) + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 14, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = parse(text = levels(plot30$Station))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face='bold'))
```

I have tried putting ifelse statements in the fill statement like this (as seen in a couple other questions and online sources), but it doesn't work for me as coded.

```
geom_tile(aes(fill = if (Perc_Diff >= 100) {'yellow'} else if (Perc_Diff) <= -100 {'blue'} else {'Perc_Diff')), color = 'black')
```

Do I need to switch to a manual scale here to get this to work?  I'd really like to avoid that if possible, to keep the continuous scale between -100 and +100.  Any help would be wonderful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is a potential solution, but the figure looks a little 'weird' as the colors (Perc Diff) and label (stuff) sometimes match, sometimes don't match.

Regardless, here is how I would split the dataset into 3 'groups' for plotting (<= -100 , > -100 & < 100, >= 100):

```
ggplot(plot30) +
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff < 100 & Perc_Diff > -100), 
            aes(x = Comp_Data,
                y = factor(Station, levels = unique(Station)),
                fill = Perc_Diff), color='black') +
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff <= -100), 
            aes(x = Comp_Data,
                y = factor(Station, levels = unique(Station))),
                fill = "blue", color='black') +
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff >= 100), 
            aes(x = Comp_Data,
                y = factor(Station, levels = unique(Station))),
                fill = "yellow", color='black') +
  geom_text(aes(x = Comp_Data,
                y = factor(Station, levels = unique(Station)),
                label = stuff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = 'white', high = "red",
                       limits=c(min(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T),
                                max(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T))) +
  ggtitle(paste('30 Day Precipitation Comparison (Inches) for', "date_30",'to',"date_1",'\nCell Values Represent Differences (SD Mesonet minus QPE; Inches)')) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(3, "cm")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0))) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 14, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face='bold'))
```

[image: example_1.png]

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I will answer my question to show the final solution.  The one issue I'm still having is that the data is reversed from the labels (the data on the y axis is reversed for some reason).  Would you also know how I can bold only the values in the yellow and blue cells?  Thank you, again.

Comment: If you turn Station into a factor (as I did in my answer) you can control the ordering of the y axis. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716245/ggplot2-changing-the-order-of-stacks-on-a-bar-graph for more details. I don't know how to bold certain values sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
png(filename = "E:\\Precip_QC_Folder\\New_Output\\30_day_pp.png",height = 3000, width = 2250, res = 250)
ggplot(plot30) + 
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff > -100 & Perc_Diff < 100),
            aes(x = Comp_Data, y = Station, fill = Perc_Diff), color='black') +
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff <= -100),
            aes(x = Comp_Data, y = Station), fill = 'lightblue', color= 'black') + 
  geom_tile(data = plot30 %>% filter(Perc_Diff >= 100),
            aes(x = Comp_Data, y = Station), fill = 'yellow', color= 'black') +
  geom_text(aes(x = Comp_Data, y = Station, label = stuff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "lightgreen", mid = 'white', high = "orange",limits=c(min(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T), max(plot30$Perc_Diff,na.rm=T))) + 
  ggtitle(paste('30 Day Precipitation Comparison (Inches) for',date_30,'to',date_1,'\nCell Values Represent Differences (SD Mesonet minus QPE; Inches)')) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(3, "cm")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0))) + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 14, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = parse(text = levels(plot30$Station))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face='bold'))
dev.off()
```